# grid flickering with checkbox and edit method

Tags: checkbox, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

My purpose is to translate interactively a checkbox action into a couple of values `"0001"` or `""`.

I placed this method on a table whose name is `Notification`.

```
// BP Deviation Documented
edit NoYesId  provenWarranty (boolean _set = false, NoYesId _provenWarranty = NoYes::No)
{
    NoYesId provenWarr;
    ;
    // set value
    if (_set)
    {
        if (_provenWarranty)
            this.Func_Status = '0001';
        else
            this.Func_Status = '';
        return _provenWarranty;
    }

    // read value
    if (this.Func_Status == '0001')
        return NoYes::Yes;
    else
        return NoYes::No;    
}
```

This method is used by a Checkbox in a Form with this Table as a Datasource.
This method has been cached in the `Notification` datasource `init()` method.

```
Notification_ds.cacheAddMethod(tablemethodstr(Notification, provenWarranty));
```

My problem is that the Checkbox is constantly flickering, is there a way to avoid that ?

**Update**

- The flickering appears inside the Checkbox design, but without
  toggling it between checked or not.
- This problem appears even if the Checkbox is connected to a basic
  datasource field, not only if connected to an edit method.
- It seems that the more fields there are in the datasource, the more
  flickering I get.

Comment: When you say flickering, do you mean visually or is it actually toggling on/off?

Comment: I mean visually, no toggling of the checkbox. In fact I see that it is not related to edit methods : same behaviour with a checkbox linked to a data column. I suspect this is a very standard problem in dynamics ax, with a very usual way to fix, because it reminds me something, but what ?

Comment: Is there code in the form's active method or could you provide an .xpo file of the form?

Comment: No there is no code in the form datasource active method ; I cannot easily provide a .xpo file, but I started to reduce the problem with a simpler form (one datasource only, no edit methods, still flickering). See my update of the question, too.